# How to remove padding from encrypted data using TLS 1.2 and rustls?

Tags: security, encryption, rust, padding, tls1.2

I'm trying to use [rustls](https://crates.io/crates/rustls) to encrypt data that will be sent over TCP. I thought of using TLS 1.2 to secure the connection. The cost of data usage in my use-cases is pretty constraining, so I was wondering if I could remove the padding from the algorithm.

Comment: What padding are you talking about?

Comment: Padding added by encryption algorithms @JamesPolk

Comment: That padding is insignificant compared to the all the rest of the overhead added by TLS.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using AES in CBC mode as the selected block cipher. You could use it in CTR mode, which doesn't use padding at all.